# How do I justify studying an effect found in an underdeveloped country when it has been found and studied in developed countries?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, thesis, writing-style

I am finding it challenging to motivate my chapter, in particular, why I have to study for a behavioral effect that influences prices in a underdeveloped country, when it has been reported in other developed markets like the US.
My area of interest is behavioral finance.

How would I convince my supervisors that this is important, even for a small country? I would greatly appreciate feedback.

Comment: Is there any reason to expect that the effect, if known to influence prices in developed countries, would therefore influence prices in undeveloped countries? If not, then to me this seems an entirely reasonable thing to investigate, unless the effect (whether present or not present) in undeveloped countries is of no interest to anyone, because regardless of what is found, one has learned something about the consistency of the effect over varying degrees of "country developness".

Comment: As it deals with the content of research it is off topic here, but ask yourself, what would be the consequences if it is learned that there is a different effect in less developed countries.